# Authentication failed due to an internal error: PASSWORD_VERIFIER challenge encountered not at the start of authentication flow

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Here is the common code, except maybe "signout" call.

```
    final CognitoUser user = awsUserPool.getUser(email);
    user.signOut();
    user.getSessionInBackground(new AuthenticationHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(CognitoUserSession userSession, CognitoDevice newDevice) { usefulfunction(); }

        @Override
        public void getAuthenticationDetails(AuthenticationContinuation authenticationContinuation, String userId) { 

                // The API needs user sign-in credentials to continue
                AuthenticationDetails authenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails(userId, password, null);
                // Pass the user sign-in credentials to the continuation
                authenticationContinuation.setAuthenticationDetails(authenticationDetails);
                // Allow the sign-in to continue
                authenticationContinuation.continueTask();
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Exception exception) { showError(exception) }
        @Override
        public void getMFACode(MultiFactorAuthenticationContinuation continuation) {//empty}

        @Override
        public void authenticationChallenge(ChallengeContinuation continuation) {//empty}

    }
```

When getSessionInBackground runs it calls getAuthenticationDetails then onSuccess and then onFailure with the following error:

"com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.exceptions.CognitoInternalErrorException: Authentication failed due to an internal error: PASSWORD_VERIFIER challenge encountered not at the start of authentication flow"

If remove signOut call, then code works fine.

So my question, why? Another question, how to force AWS to request password?

Answer (score 2):

Have you recently updated to AWS client v2.12.1?

I was getting this error and as a workaround if you downgrade to v2.12.0 the problem no longer occurs.

Comment: I have the following dependencies in build.gradle:     `//Base SDK
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.12.0'
    //AppSync SDK
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-appsync:2.7.+'` but I still have the same exception. Before I used aws SDK 2.11.+ version. Did I miss anything?